# Casting char to uint sets all MSB

Tags: c, casting, char, int

I wonder why a one-line casting of a char to unsigned integer (uint16_t or higher) sets all bits 8-15 to 1. While two step casting keeps bit 8-15 at 0. Am I doing something wrong/weird or is the "safe" way to always `& 0xFF` when casting char to larger integers than 8 bits? E.g. in the code below, `b` will get the correct value if I do this:

```
uint16_t b = (uint16_t) ((*readChar)[0] & 0xFF);
```

Code: (I put the extra `printf` in the end in case the first `printf` which prints the values was fooling me)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void GetChar(char**);

int main() {
    char* readChar;
    GetChar(&readChar);
    return 0;
}

void GetChar(char** readChar) {
    uint16_t val = 3001;
    uint16_t* valPtr = &val;

    *readChar = (char*) valPtr;

    uint8_t a = (*readChar)[0];               // 185
    uint16_t b = (uint16_t) (*readChar)[0];   // 65465= b'1111 1111 1011 1001'
    uint16_t c = (uint16_t) a;                // 185= b'0000 0000 1011 1001'

    printf("%u %u %u", a, b, c);              // <====== this prints 185 65465 185

    if (c==b) {
        printf("YES\n");
    } else {
        printf("NO\n");                       // <=== Always end up here
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your compiler's `char` signed, and its value in the range `0x80` to `0xFF`? For example, if the `char` value is `-1` how would you think that is converted to `uint16_t`? Please show some specific examples.

Comment: @WeatherVane isn't the value 3001 in the example above not specific enough? I have no idea of the compiler's char sign settings

Comment: It isn't a setting, it is a compiler definition. `char` may be signed or unsigned, depending on the implementation. Suppose you have `char a = 0xFF; printf("%d\n", a);` the output will be `-1` or `255`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your system, `char` has range of -128 to 127.  (This is common). It cannot hold the value 185 as you suggest. The value that you are calling 185 is actually 256-185, which is `-71`.

Converting `-71` to unsigned 16-bit is defined as `65536 - 71` which is `65465`. (All conversion of negative integers to unsigned works this way).

You could use the `(uint8_t)a` technique to convert `-71` to `185`;  or just use `uint8_t` instead of `char` in the first place.

Comment: Good answer. Thing is, the code is running on a  microcontroller seemingly flawlessly, it's when I wrote and ran the unit tests on win/cygwin that this occured. But ok, implementing the `(uint16_t) a` trick for the sake of unit tests isn't such a bad idea perhaps.

Comment: Question remains why b and c are treated differently...?

Comment: @niCkcAMel my answer already explained that. `b` is assigned the value `(uint16_t) -71` which is `65465` and `c` is assigned the value `(uint16_t)185` which is `185`.